# Asterisk cannot create databases

Tags: database, asterisk

I have a question.

Before question, my server setting is,

OS : centOS 5.9
Elastix : Elastix 2.4.0
Asterisk : asterisk 11.15.0
Mysql : 5.0.95

I create 960 peers. (Because of peer to peer call)
When I type 'sip show peers' in asterisk cli, asterisk returns 960 peers info.
When I connect to any peer, Connection is OK.
But, When I try to call peer1 to peer2, I cannot call peer2.
I debugged 'why cannot call?'.
Finally, I found answer.

In call flow, The server cannot find a peer2.
So, When I typed 'database show' in asterisk cli, asterisk database was abnormal.

I create 960 sip peers.
But, In asterisk DB, 
AMPUSER is about 500.
CALLTRACE is about 40.
CW is about 2000.
DEVICE is about 100.

What is this...?

How can i solve this problem?
I already execute 'reload' and Hardware reboot, asterisk restart....etc...
But, same problem..

Please help me..

How can i reset asterisk databases?

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk database not used for call when you call SIP/peername and peername is in asterisk realtime(database)

Options which affect behavour are

```
rtcachefriends=yes|no
rtautoclear = yes|no
```

Note, if your peers using 3g it is very likly they change addresses often(so address in database is NOT valid anymore)